# issues with running firebase init and firebase deploy on Mac

Tags: firebase

I am trying to initialize a firebase project on my Mac but am getting an error when I try to install dependencies with npm. I am also getting an error when I try to run firebase deploy.

run firebase init:
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for firebase-admin@^111.5.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'business-continuity-codebase'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.npm/_logs/2023-02-14T23_09_34_698Z-debug.log

run firebase deploy:

1:7 error 'functions' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: eslint .
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.npm/_logs/2023-02-14T23_16_39_827Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

1. Change "firebase-admin": "^111.5.0" to "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0" in package.json
2. Run $Firebase init functions command again and chose an **overwrite** option
3. Type Yes everywhere except: File functions/package.json already exists. Overwrite? Answer - No
4. Type Yes for Install dependencies